# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>')

Tags: javascript, opencart

Не могу понять в чем дело... Выдает ошибку "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://...') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://...')."
Подскажите в чем проблема и как ее можно решить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И к тому-же, ошибок становиться больше и больше каждую секунду

Answer (score 0):

Сайт у вас открыт по https протоколу. Скрипт подключен по http протоколу. Соответственно скрипт не может получить доступ к контенту в целях безопасности.
Вот собственно и вся причина. Нужно просто перевести текст ошибки.

Comment: Не подскажите где это решить? Сайт на опенкарте

Comment: Смотрите по коду, где у вас подключается этот скрипт. Где именно в опенкарте - я представления не имею. Вы должны добиться, чтобы всё у вас подключалось по https протоколу, пока браузерная строка не покажет, что ваш сайт имеет безопасное соединение. В адресной строке должен быть зелёный замок.

Comment: Сайт у меня открыт по Http протаколу, если что... Так что дело не в этом

Comment: @ИванВальчук это же ваш [скрин консоли?](https://monosnap.com/image/6nzsi1xRUUfdSDDsncGss5bXCrPZbt.png)